# How to keep the data state on a listview when the back button is pressed?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a listview which contains a timer and a start/stop button, the timer works the challenge I'm facing is to keep the state of the listview case when I press the back button, I want my data to be retained where I left off as in I want the timer to be continuing when I return to the page instead of loading data again. I'm using MVVM.
[image]

Comment: you should probably create the Timer in your App class, not an individual page

Comment: You can override `OnDisappearing` method to store the data in your listview page .

Answer (score 0):

If you're following MVVM design philosophy then you'll already be processing the data that you display in your list view within the associated ViewModel.

Ideally you'll have bound your Button to a Command that is used to start your processing.
If you ensure that you don't destroy your ViewModel when navigating away from the associated View or overwrite it when navigating back to the View (page) that is displaying your data, you can then implement a Command to pause the processing and the timer.

Alternatively, there is no reason why you can't have a class that controls this processing that is then referenced by the ViewModel in a similar vein to the Controller within MVC.

You don't say how much data you need to process, so you may need to look at storing it to media of some sort if its a lot of data and you're unsure about keeping it in memory.